# Get championName by his ID in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, api, android-asynctask

So im working on Android App which will show last 10 matches with details of Summoner.
I have "key" of champion but i need his name. In data dragon i found this link:
http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.22.1/img/champion/Aatrox.png
And i want somehow retrive champName by his "key" because i want download champion Image.
Im using this library: https://github.com/taycaldwell/riot-api-java

```
class Wrapper
{
    Summoner summoner;
    MatchList matchList;
    RiotApi api;
    //Champion champion;
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public class FetchMatchListTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    @Override
    protected Wrapper doInBackground(String... params) {

        ApiConfig config = new ApiConfig().setKey("MY-API-KEY");
        wrapper.api = new RiotApi(config);

        try {
            //wrapper.champion = wrapper.api.getDataChampion(Platform.EUNE, match.getChampion());
            wrapper.summoner = wrapper.api.getSummonerByName(Platform.EUNE, params[0]);
            wrapper.matchList = wrapper.api.getMatchListByAccountId(Platform.EUNE, wrapper.summoner.getAccountId());
            return wrapper;
        } catch (RiotApiException e) {
            Log.d("RiotMSG", "Blad: "+ RiotApiException.getMessage(e.getErrorCode()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper wrapp) {
        super.onPostExecute(wrapp);
        if(wrapp != null) {
            numOfGamesText.setText(String.valueOf(wrapp.matchList.getTotalGames()));
        }

        if (wrapp == null) { throw new NullPointerException("wrapp.matchList object is null"); }

        if (wrapp.matchList.getMatches() != null) {
            for (MatchReference match : wrapp.matchList.getMatches()) {
                if(matchLimitCounter == 10) break;
                else{
                    matchLimitCounter++;

                    int key = match.getChampion();
                    //wrapp.champion = wrapper.api.getDataChampion(Platform.EUNE, key);
                    //String champName = wrapp.champion.getName();

                    //Here i will send my championName to my own Match class and then i will 
                    //put img in ImageView using picasso and datadragon champion assest link
                    Match match1 = new Match(wrapp.summoner.getProfileIconId(), match.getLane(), key, "lala");
                    matchList.add(match1);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know i can do something like this in onPostExecute and it will give me champion name:

```
wrapp.champion = wrapper.api.getDataChampion(Platform.EUNE, key);
String champName = wrapp.champion.getName();
```

But im getting this error NetworkOnMainThreadException because i cant use network in Main Thread, but only in onPostExecute i got my "key" of champion which is needed to use Champion class for getDataChampion(Platform, key), so how to resolve this? Maybe i can just send the "key" and then using champion.json: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.22.1/data/en_US/champion.json loop all json file until i find my "key" and get my name, but i don't know how to do this.

**EDITED**

```
class Wrapper
{
    Summoner summoner;
    MatchList matchList;
    RiotApi api;
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public class FetchMatchListTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    @Override
    protected Wrapper doInBackground(String... params) {

        ApiConfig config = new ApiConfig().setKey("MY-API-KEY");
        wrapper.api = new RiotApi(config);
        Champion champion;

        try {
            //wrapper.champion = wrapper.api.getDataChampion(Platform.EUNE, match.getChampion());
            wrapper.summoner = wrapper.api.getSummonerByName(Platform.EUNE, params[0]);
            wrapper.matchList = wrapper.api.getMatchListByAccountId(Platform.EUNE, wrapper.summoner.getAccountId());

            if (wrapper.matchList.getMatches() != null) {
                for (MatchReference match : wrapper.matchList.getMatches()) {
                    if(matchLimitCounter == 10) break;
                    else{
                        matchLimitCounter++;

                        int key = match.getChampion();
                        champion = wrapper.api.getDataChampion(Platform.EUNE, key);
                        String champName = champion.getName();

                        //Here i will send my championName to my own Match class and then i will put img in ImageView using picasso
                        //and datadragon champion assest link
                        Match myMatch = new Match(wrapper.summoner.getProfileIconId(), champName, key, "lala");
                        matchList.add(myMatch);

                    }
                }
            }

            return wrapper;
        } catch (RiotApiException e) {
            Log.d("RiotMSG", "Blad: "+ RiotApiException.getMessage(e.getErrorCode()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper wrapp) {
        super.onPostExecute(wrapp);
        if(wrapp != null) {
            numOfGamesText.setText(String.valueOf(wrapp.matchList.getTotalGames()));
        }

        if (wrapp == null) { throw new NullPointerException("wrapp.matchList object is null"); }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are those wrapper operations related to network/IO ?

```
wrapp.champion = wrapper.api.getDataChampion(Platform.EUNE, key);
String champName = wrapp.champion.getName();
```

If yes, move them in `doInBackground` instead of `onPostExecute`. Because they are heavy oerations and must be executed off main thread which is `onPostExecute` above case.

Comment: [Look Edit] So i moved all to doInBackground but now im getting error that wrapp = null

Comment: Debug starting inside doInBackground and check `wrapper` is instantiated or not

Comment: The problem was getDataChampion() from library returning 403, same as here: https://github.com/taycaldwell/riot-api-java/issues/148 , so only way i see to get championName is send my "key" and using it and champion.json file to get name from there i think

Comment: Thank you for your time and help.